# PVC pipe in front of furnace

Tags: furnace

There is a pvc pipe as part of the installation of my furnace. The red cap (circled) was off and water was overflowing. I pushed the cap in, but I'm concerned that, maybe, that's the wrong thing to do. Any advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That should be a condensate drain line.  I think the red cap was meant to be inplace. I'm not very familiar with furnaces, (In Fla. it all heatpumps or AC units.) I'll let the HVAC experts give the definitive answer.

Comment: I think a condensate drain line makes sense. Running the heater today due to the storm. I'm still wondering why it is overflowing, though. Maybe a block upstream? And I hope it doesn't explode because I put the cap on, lol. (I'm not really lol'ing.)

Comment: Pop the cap off. Condensate is supposed to get out, whether through the drain or overflow. Your drain is blocked. (Deal with that later.) Put a bucket under for overflow.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will.

Comment: I noticed a little brush hanging on the pipe and tried brushing out the pipe. I do see some  debris in the tube and broke it up. The water level dropped down an inch or so. I put a pail underneath. I'll keep my eye on it for the rest of the day - I feel much better. Rather water than explosion. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: the inflow side of a p-trap should be higher than the outflow side.

Comment: really the condensate should be air-gaped from a sewer connection as right now you can have sewer backup into your furnace.

Comment: The photo is a little too close-range: we can't see where the pipes originate or their destination. That info makes a difference as we try to sort out how it should be operating.

Comment: There are two lines that disappear around the sides of the furnace. Where do they go? Do they both run to a drain or other drain pipe? If the one on the left side runs to drain, but the one on the right side is a drain output from something else, then the trap levels are definitely backwards.

Comment: The line on the right goes all the way back to the garage wall. The one on the left is piped into the corner of the furnace.

Comment: And, unsurprisingly, I can't even get a furnace repair company to come out yet. I'm on a waiting list JUST to get an appointment - they are not even making appointments no matter how far into the future.

Comment: And, for whatever reason, the level of the water in the overflow pipe #1 has dropped - no longer overflowing nor within reach of my finger. And, yet, we've been running the heater all day. So, I'm thinking that following everyone's advice and using the brush to clear out the pipe may have helped unblock something. Or it simply unblocked from built-up pressure. I'll keep my eye on it for a few days.

Answer (score 2):

If I’m reading the pic correctly, the cap is off the lower side of the U tube trap.  Water will flow out of the lower side as a rule, so replacing the cap may be all you need to do.  I would also pop the cap off the horizontal line attached to the left side of the U tube and poke a brush or rod as far into it as you can, to poke a hole if it is clogged.  If it’s clogged, clean it out.  All this you can do yourself.

Comment: Good catch that the cap was on the low side, which makes my comment wrong. Just be sure that the outflow is draining -- it's pretty common for it to clog.

Comment: Hi. I took a far shot to help see the full installation. I numbered the pipes to help communication. So, it's overflowing #1 pretty rapidly now. I used the brush to try to clean out from #1 and took the cap off #2 and used the brush. Aside from calling the furnace guys, I don't know what else I should do. (BTW, thanks very much for the responses!)